# App wide Event listener on class in NextJs

Tags: next.js, event-listener

I am trying to add an event listener for every element on the page that I assign a class to in NextJS. I have added this logic in the _app page as I thought this would be a good place to place the logic as I want this all over the app with any child components that contain element with the aforementioned class.

Currently this logic is not working as my querySelectorAll doesn't find any of the elements with the class.

Here is my code:

My _app.ts file

```
const clickEventListener = (e: Event) => {
  const { target = {} } = e;

  try {
    const urlObject = new URL((target as HTMLLinkElement).href);
    const { origin, href } = urlObject;
    if (origin === process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WEBSITE_LINK) {
      window.location.href = forwardWithAuthHelper(href);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
};

const App = ({ Component, pageProps, router: { query } }: AppPropsWithLayout) => {
  // Use the layout defined at the page level, if available
  const isProduction = process.env.NEXT_ENV === 'production';
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page);
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof document === 'undefined') {
      return;
    }

    const forwardWithAuthElements = document.querySelectorAll('.forward-with-auth');
    console.log(forwardWithAuthElements);

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-plusplus
    for (let i = 0; i < forwardWithAuthElements.length; i++) {
      forwardWithAuthElements[i].addEventListener('click', clickEventListener);
    }
    
    return () => {
      document?.removeEventListener('click', () => {});
    };
  }, []);

  if (router.query?.logout) {
    removeAuthCookies();
    router.push('/login');
  }

  return (
    <CacheBuster
      currentVersion={packageInfo.version}
      isEnabled={isProduction}
      isVerboseMode={false}
      loadingComponent={<LoadingSpinner />}
    >
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <WithAuthToken token={String(query?.token || '')}>
            {getLayout(
              <>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
                {!hideToastsUrls.includes(router.pathname) && <Toasts />}
              </>,
            )}
          </WithAuthToken>
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    </CacheBuster>
  );
};
```

The elements that have this class can be anywhere around the app in any components.

Can anyone see why the document is not picking up any of these elements? I was thinking maybe the child components have not rendered before this logic is applied therefore it isn't aware of the elements. Maybe some kind of Document ready logic is required here but I am not sure.